# FireMonkey TMenuBar Memory Leaks

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Create a new HD Firemonkey Application in Delphi XE2.

Drop a TMenuBar on the form. Edit at design time and add a 'Foo' menuitem, add a child item 'Bar'.

Turn memory leak reporting on in .dpr

```
ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := true;
```

Run app. Click 'Bar' as many times as you can be bothered to...

Is it just me or do memory leaks abound?

TList x2
Unknown x1
Position x4
TBounds x3, Unknown x1
TPopup x1

(per click)

Should I be concerned by this?

Comment: Have you filed this with Embarcadero QC? They fix stuff like this you know, or at least explain it.

Comment: QC report logged thanks. Should I not use the TMenuBar until this is fixed or will delphi garbage collection deal with this and actually it's of no real concern? At what point does a memory leak like this become a real concern? Obviously in this case, the memory leak is compounded every time you click the menuitem which is something to consider.

Comment: Any memory leak is a concern, but you really don't have many options other than TMenuBar.  Embarcadero is coming out with Firemonkey updates almost on a monthly schedule, so it may be fixed in the near future.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. Get your friends to vote on the report. Unfortunately, my votes are used up.

Comment: We should not have to vote on this, its a memory leak and should be fixed!  But I know what you are saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of those are owned by the Popup in TMenuItem.Popup() in FMX.Menus.

If you free the Popup object at the end, all of the leaks go away.

It's a blatant bug, but easily fixed.

I modified the source file and and placed it in my project's folder until they release the bug fix.

Comment: not sure what I'm missing here, I tried:

`type
  TNewMenuItem = class(TMenuItem)
    procedure PopUp; override;
  end;`

but I get a compiler error: can't override non-virtual method. Fair enough. So I tried:

`type
  TNewMenuItem = class(TMenuItem)
    procedure PopUp; reintroduce;
  end;`

but the FMX.Menus implementation is still called. I then tried declaring:

`procedure NewPopUp;`

and assigning my MenuItem.PopUp to this new procedure but I get a 'left side cannot be assigned to' error. How did you implement this?

Comment: @Steve, I fixed the problem in the FMX.Menus source file and copied it to to my local project file. I thought that you would be able to hide the method, but didn't try it. I'll modify my answer. Apparently, there are other barriers.

Comment: Could you post the code snippet that you updated? If I call FreeAndNil(Popup) in the finally section of the TMenuItem.Popup I get a multi-free memory leak using EurekaLog. Admittedly if I turn EurekaLog off and leave ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown on then the memory leaks are no longer reported but I'm inclined to believe EurekaLog is correct.